# Таб-бар в таб-баре

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard

Как можно сделать следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть *таб-бар контроллер* (серый слева), у него есть три вкладки - две голубых и одна серая (справа).

Нужно, чтобы пользователь нажал на третью вкладку, и в ней у него была возможность переключиться еще на несколько других вкладок.

Как в *storyboard* настроить связь *Page View Controller'а* с красными вкладками?

Между вкладками третьего меню желательно, чтобы пользователь мог переключаться сдвигом (но можно и нажатием на кнопку еще одного *таб-бара*).

Возможно, это нужно как-то по-другому реализовывать?

Comment: Два таб-бара на одном экране это слишком. Я бы предложил использовать UISegmentedControl или UIPageViewController.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! PageController хорошая мысль, но я что-то никак не могу понять как к нему добавлять вью контроллеры. т.е. я его размести в сторибоард, а какую связь использовать, чтобы к нему присоединить размещенные в сторибоард вьюхи..

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/ вот тутор по PageController
Так же еще можно использовать UICollectionView смотря какие цели

Comment: Спасибо за туориал! .В каком плане цели ? Мне нужно так, чтобы, когда пользователь нажал на кнопку в меню таб бара, ему показались еще несколько вьюх. Точнее первая вьюха, потом пользователь(желателньо свайпом) перешел на следующую и если нужно назад.

Comment: @hell_ghost, смотрел по вашему туториалу и еще несколько как использовать PAgeViewController, но не могу разобраться как скормить контроллеру 3 вьюхи, которые я создал в storyboard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это можно сделать двумя путями, используя navigation controller или используя container view. Оба способа хороши если во втором tab view контроллере скрыть сам таб бар а вместо него использовать segmented control.

В первом случае это будет выглядеть так:
[image: navigation controller + tab bar controller + segment control]

Во втором случае так:
[image: container view + tab bar controller + segment control]